# How to use findAll() function in python

Tags: python

hi how can I use findAll() function in python to access this div?

```
<div id="containerTable" data-webcallurls="[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=142.1.MRC.PHS&amp;chartType=1d&amp;isETF=false&amp;iseod=False&amp;lang=en-PH&amp;isCS=true&amp;isVol=true&quot;}]"><ul>
```

I tried this but I'm getting syntax error:

```
containers2 = soup.findAll("div", id_='containerTable', data-webcallurls_='[{"url":"https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=142.1.MRC.PHS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-PH&isCS=true&isVol=true"}]')
```

Comment: Please provide more info, i.e. the code you are using and input data to make it [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

1. The edit by user @r0ei fixes one of the syntax errors. You need a comma after `id_='containerTable'`.
2. `data-webcallurls_` is not a valid variable name (because of the hyphen) and hence not a valid keyword argument. [The documentation provides an example of exactly this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments):

   > Some attributes, like the data-* attributes in HTML 5, have names that can’t be used as the names of keyword arguments:
   >
   > ```
   > data_soup = BeautifulSoup('<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>')
   > data_soup.find_all(data-foo="value")
   > # SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
   > ```
   >
   > You can use these attributes in searches by putting them into a dictionary and passing the dictionary into find_all() as the attrs argument:
   >
   > ```
   > data_soup.find_all(attrs={"data-foo": "value"})
   > # [<div data-foo="value">foo!</div>]
   > ```
3. `id` should be passed in as `id=...`, not `id_=....` - you don't need the trailing underscore.

Finally, your call should look like this:

```py
containers2 = soup.find_all("div",
                            id='containerTable',
                            attrs={'data-webcallurls_': '[{"url":"https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=142.1.MRC.PHS&chartType=1d&isETF=false&iseod=False&lang=en-PH&isCS=true&isVol=true"}]'}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to scrape the table on this website: https://www.msn.com/en-ph/money/stockdetails/history/phs-mrc/fi-alvxww

Comment: I think this div is where I can get the data and run a for loop to get the historical price but it won't even let me print price:
<div id="containerTable" data-webcallurls="[{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https://finance-services.msn.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=142.1.MRC.PHS&amp;chartType=1d&amp;isETF=false&amp;iseod=False&amp;lang=en-PH&amp;isCS=true&amp;isVol=true&quot;}]"><ul>
            <li class="rowvalue date">12:41 PM</li>
            <li class="rowvalue high">0.25</li>
            <li class="rowvalue low">0.25</li>
            <li class="rowvalue open">0.25</li>

Comment: **You haven't shown your code or what you've tried.** Also, you need to use [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) since the 'data-webcallurls_'. What you see in the inspector is already html-un-escape'ed for you, so you can't just copy-paste that. Also, since you have the `div` id and it is unique, you don't need the 'webcalls' url part to identify the div uniquely.